# Python interpreter not available for selection in vscode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I am not able to find and select the python virtual interpreter from vscode. I can see virtual environments i created previously but i can't find the one i just created. I am using *vscode 1.46.*

Steps

1. Created a new directory and changed to that directory
2. Used pipenv shell. pipfile file got created. I then installed a mysql connector using pipenv install. Piplock.file got created.
3. Used **CMD + SHIFT + P** on my mac to select the interpreter.

I do not see the interpreter in the list. But I do see the interpreter in my finder. Is there any reason why vscode is not detecting it. There is an option to select the interpreter but the 
***.local*** folder does not show when browsing the directory from vscode.

Here is what my vscode setting for this project looks like.
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So not entirely sure this is the recommended/right way but i went to my vscode settings and added the virtual environment directory for this project manually.